# Gettting an error while creating delta table from Azure Synapse notebook

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm trying to create a delta table from Azure Synapse Notebook. I was getting an error. I also added my current IP address to the storage account. I was able to write as a delta file but when I am trying to create a delta table it throws an error. I Checked all Microsoft documents for this issue they are telling me to add an IP address to the storage account. Is that anything I am missing or else it is a bug? Thanks in Advance.

Error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Got exception: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, HEAD, https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/xxxxxxxfilesystem/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90)org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:112)org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.createDatabase(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:193)org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:137)org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:124)org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:44)org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$catalog$1(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:59)org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:98)org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:98)org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.databaseExists(SessionCatalog.scala:266)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates, your account doesn't have enough permissions to the workspace.
Add the RBAC Storage Blob Data Contributor to the user that is running the notebook.

You can go through the links from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/565482/i-am-getting-error-while-running-the-spark-job-wit.html).